# Analyzer Mindray BS240 keep resetting the connection

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm trying to communicate using TCP with the chemestry analyzer "Mindray BS240". The problem is that the analyzer keep disconnecting and reconnecting. Here is my code, what did I miss ?

```py
soc = socket.socket()
print('Socket succesfully created')
port = 7118
receiving_address= ""
soc.bind((receiving_address, port))
print (f'socket binded to port{port}')
soc.listen(5)
print('Socket is listening')
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    while True:
        try:
                
            data = c.recv(8192)  # Receive data from the client
            if not data:
                print("no data")
                response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n"  # Create the response with status code 200
                c.send(response.encode()) 
                c.close() 

                break  # If no data is received, break the loop
           


            print(response_message)
            print()
            print()

            h = hl7.parse(str(response_message))

            response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n"  # Create the response with status code 200
            c.send(response.encode())
```

output:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Got connection from ('192.168.20.20', 49229)

[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Got connection from ('192.168.20.20', 49230)

[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```